# Decrypting an executable file under windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

I had a fully encrypted directory of code, that I had to work with under Windows now (coming from a Unix based system).

I decrypted everything, and got some errors:

- All the executable files (`.bat` and `.exe`, as well as `.whl` files for some reason, to be precise) could not be decrypted.
- Using the `cipher /d` / `chipher /d /f` command changed nothing: It gives me an access denied.

I want to have those files unencrypted. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/264064

Comment: So, what happens if you just use the right-click Properties->General->Advanced button to remove encryption on a single file?

Comment: @egray I tried this already. Same error.

Comment: @sigalor It doesn't look like this will help, as it could decrypt all other files without problems.

Comment: @sigalor and the article does not apply to Windows 7, just to Windows Server.